# Create a single iOS framework-file from ZXing QR reader project

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, qr-code

I have been looking for 2 days now, trying to find a way to get a single iOS framework-file for the ZXing QR reader. The only thing i can find, is a ZXingWidget project to include in my own project. But here, i have to add path's, dependencies etc. for it to work.

Isn't there a way to create one single .framework file that can easily be added to any new projects needing this feature?

I have found a kstenerud iOS framework template to create frameworks, but i can't make it work with the ZXing project.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no good solution for this for iOS.

Frameworks are generally (always?) dynamically-linked libraries and Apple doesn't allow DLLs on iOS. Note that [there are now framework builds for OS X](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/zxing/3_9RVmR7xIw/discussion).

It may be possible to hack Xcode to produce a framework with a statically linked library, but that's going against Apple's patterns which means I suspect it will push Xcode into corner cases which fail in subtle and hard to debug ways and which have a high chance of breaking across Xcode versions.

This opinion comes in part from talking to Apple Xcode engineers at WWDC about cleaning up the ZXing project files. There are new project files now that follow all the best practices they recommended but on iOS they still require the same include path and library linkage project customization that the old project files require.